# Rescan starts not from first block

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, bitcoin.conf, rescan

I have a complete blockchain but when I set `rescan = 1` in .conf file my bitcoind starts rescaning from 435000 block. How to start it from the first block? What's wrong with my blockchain?

Comment: I’m not sure if I fully understand your question.  Try to remove the rescan from .conf file and take a look there https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/rescanblockchain.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Bitcoin Core v0.16 and later, it is recommended to rescan the blockchain using the `rescanblockchain` RPC rather than the `-rescan` parameter (which will be removed in the latest release). The default start height of this RPC is `0`, so you can simply run `rescanblockchain` with no parameters to rescan the entire chain.